# SQLAlchemy: insert record if certain record and relationship data does not already exist

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, filtering, exists

I want to know how to query data from multiple tables with multiple conditions.

My example db has the following tables:

```
class Location(Base):
    __tablename__ = "location"

    id = Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True)
    location = Column('Location', String)

class Person(Base):
    __tablename__ = "person"

    id = Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column('Name', String, unique=True)
    profession = Column('Profession', String)
    location_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('location.id'))
    location = relationship(Location)
```

We have in this database a person with a specific location. My goal is to write a query where I can check conditions of the `Location` table and the `Person` table.

A person with the name Eric lives in Houston. Now I want to know if I already have an Eric from Houston in my database.

The following query doesn't work.

```
new_location = Location(location='Houston')
obj = Person(name='Eric', profession='Teacher', location=new_location)

if session.query(Person).filter(Person.name == obj.name,
Person.profession == obj.profession,
Person.location_id == obj.location.id).first() == None:
session.add(obj)
session.commit()
print("Insert sucessful")
```

The problem in my query is the last line where I check the location but I don't know how to solve it. Maybe someone has a working example with the SQLAlchemy method `exists()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like the following to join `Person` and `Location` and filter for any record where the name and location are the same as the new person instance you have created. The query will either return the record or `None`, so you can use the result in your `if` (remember that indentation matters - maybe the code example in your question just copied incorrectly).

```
new_location = Location(location='Houston')
new_person = Person(name='Eric', profession='Teacher', location=new_location)

person_location_exists = session.query(Person).\
    join(Location).\
    filter(Person.name == new_person.name).\
    filter(Location.location == new_location.location).\
    first()

if not person_location_exists:
    session.add(new_person)
    session.commit()
    print("Insert successful")
```

You could use [`exists()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.exists) to accomplish the same thing, but I think the above is a bit simpler.

Comment: Hey ty for your answer! I found a very similar solution but your solution is much better :)

Comment: How do you deal with the race condition here?

Comment: @Andrew - following is some guidance I have found useful on handling race conditions: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/263726/how-to-prevent-race-conditions-in-a-web-application